# Adding BackColor Macro to all Checkboxes in an Excel Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, backcolor

I have an Excel worksheet with a large number of checkboxes. To improve visual clarity, I want the BackColor property of a given checkbox to change when it is checked (and revert back to white when unchecked). This should apply to each checkbox.

Here's my (very basic) macro to achieve this for an individual checkbox:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
      CheckBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    ElseIf CheckBox1.Value = False Then
        CheckBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If
End Sub
```

But I cannot get it to work for all checkboxes without painstakingly adding this macro for each individual checkbox. Any help is greatly appreciated (and sorry if this is a very basic question, I'm fairly new to vba)!

Comment: You can use a "control array" - see for example https://bettersolutions.com/excel/macros/vba-control-arrays.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next solution refers to **sheet ActiveX check boxes**!

1. Please, insert a class module, name it "CheckBoxCls" and copy the next short code in it:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents chkBEvent As MSForms.CheckBox

Private Sub chkBEvent_Click()
    ColorChKBackground chkBEvent
End Sub
```

2. Copy the next code in the sheet code module where you want controlling the check boxes (of ActiveX type):

```
Option Explicit

Private chkBoxes() As New CheckBoxCls

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    AllocateEvent Me
End Sub

Public Sub AllocateEvent(ws As Worksheet) 'Public...
 Dim chkBox As OLEObject, k As Long
 ReDim chkBoxes(ws.OLEObjects.count)
 For Each chkBox In ws.OLEObjects
    If TypeName(chkBox.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
      Set chkBoxes(k).chkBEvent = chkBox.Object: k = k + 1
    End If
 Next
 If k > 0 Then ReDim Preserve chkBoxes(k - 1)
End Sub
```

3. Copy the next `Sub` in a **standard module**:

```
Sub ColorChKBackground(chk As MSForms.CheckBox)
 If chk.value = True Then
    chk.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
 Else
    chk.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
 End If
End Sub
```

4. In order to allocate events from `Workbook_Open` event, you should place the next code line inside it:

```
  SheetCodeModule.AllocateEvent Worksheets("SheetName")
```

Now, "SheetName" should be, of course, the name of the sheet containing the check boxes in discussion and `SheetCodeModule` should be its code module name, which can be obtained using:

```
   Debug.Print Worksheets("SheetName").CodeName
```

in a testing sub and copying the return string, instead of `SheetCodeModule`. When you open the sheet code module to copy the above code, you can see in the left `Object Explorer` on the activated one something as `Sheet14 (SheetName)`. `Sheet14` is code module name...

Now, it will work without preliminarily deactivate/activate the sheet in discussion. But, if an error occurs the array keeping the objects will lose its content and the actual `Activate` event is good to be maintained as a backup...

Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks!

The only problem that's left now is that after opening the workbook, I always have to deactivate/reactivate the sheet with the checkboxes (by navigating to a different sheet) before ColorChKBackground actually runs. 

I tried circumventing this with a "Workbook_Open" subroutine that activates the sheet I want, but so far no results. Any additional advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @TeeBeeKay Yes, there are more ways of doing it. The simplest looks to be adapting `AllocateEvent` to receive a `Worksheet` parameter, make it `Public` and call it using the respective sheet Code module name. In fact, I will adapt the above solution to do it...

Comment: Once again, works beautifully! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "control array".  Here's an example:

In the userform module

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim colCB As Collection  '<<< must be global to stay in scope

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim con As Control
    
    Set colCB = New Collection   'initialize collection
    For Each con In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(con) = "CheckBox" Then colCB.Add GetEventWrapper(con)
    Next con
End Sub

'return an instance of `cbEvent` linked to `cb`
Function GetEventWrapper(cb As Object)
    Set GetEventWrapper = New cbEvent
    Set GetEventWrapper.cb = cb
End Function
```

Class module `cbEvent` for handling checkbox events:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents cb As MSForms.CheckBox

Private Sub cb_Click()
    If cb.Value = True Then
        cb.BackColor = vbRed
    ElseIf cb.Value = False Then
        cb.BackColor = vbWhite
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use this to set the OnAction on each of your check boxes:

```
Sub SetCheckBoxActions()
    Dim shpCheckBox As Shape
    For Each shpCheckBox In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If shpCheckBox.Type = msoFormControl Then
            If shpCheckBox.FormControlType = xlCheckBox Then
                shpCheckBox.OnAction = "ThisWorkbook.CheckBox_Click"
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Second, add the event. Put it in ThisWorkbook (or change above)

```
Public Sub CheckBox_Click()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        If .ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ElseIf .ControlFormat.Value = xlOff Then
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that it is the forecolor that changes the background.
It will work through each of your check boxes in the active sheet. That should be changed to target your sheets in a more reliable way. Don't use `ActiveSheet` without good reasons.